# Datepicker дата по количеству дней

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker

Хочу сделать приложение, в котором высчитывается срок годности продуктов. Есть datepicker, edittext и spinner. Datapicker устанавливает дату производства, а в edittext пользователь вписывает сколько дней, месяцев, годен продукт. Не могу разобраться, как это сделать и найти не могу. С datepicker разобрался, все исправно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам посоветовал посмотреть в сторону библиотеки [Material DateTime Picker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#material-datetime-picker---select-a-timedate-in-style). Это очень кастомизируемая библиотека и в числе настроек есть [настройка](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#datepickerdialog-setselectabledayscalendar-days) периода отображения:

```
setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)
```

в доках пишут:

> You can pass a Calendar[] to the DatePickerDialog. The values in this
>   list are the only acceptable dates for the picker. It takes precedence
>   over setMinDate(Calendar day) and setMaxDate(Calendar day)

в вашем случае это будет: `setMinDate(Calendar day)` и  `setMaxDate(Calendar day)` которые либа берет из массива дней которые вы ей выделили.